# With bigtable and python, what are the causes of an exception like google.api_core.exceptions.Aborted: 409 Error while reading table?

Tags: python, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I'm getting this exception when using read_rows on a table. The table has rows for features of documents, each document has 300 to 800 features and there are about 2 million documents. The row_key is the feature, the columns are the document ids that have that feature. There are billions of rows.

I'm running this on a 16 CPU VM on GCP and the load averages are between 6 and 10. I'm using the python bigtable SDK and python 3.6.8 and google-cloud-bigtable 2.3.3.

I'm getting this kind of exception when reading the rows using table.read_rows(start_key=foo#xy, end_key=foo#xz). foo#xy and foo#xy are from table.sample_row_keys(). I get 200 prefixes from sample_row_keys and I successfully process the first 5 or so before I get this error. I'm running the table.read_rows() call in a ThreadPool.

If you've encountered an exception like this and investigated it, what was the cause of it and what did you do to prevent it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bdc34/docsim/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 106, in __next__
    return next(self._wrapped)
  File "/home/bdc34/docsim/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 426, in __next__
    return self._next()
  File "/home/bdc34/docsim/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 809, in _next
    raise self
grpc._channel._MultiThreadedRendezvous: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.ABORTED
        details = "Error while reading table 'projects/arxiv-production/instances/docsim/tables/docsim' : Response was not consumed in time; terminating connection.(Possible causes: slow client data read or network problems)"
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1635477504.521060666","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:172.217.0.42:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1069,"grpc_message":"Error while reading table 'projects/arxiv-production/instances/docsim/tables/docsim' : Response was not consumed in time; terminating connection.(Possible causes: slow client data read or network problems)","grpc_status":10}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/bdc34/docsim/docsim/loading/all_common_hashes.py", line 53, in <module>
    for hash, n, c, dt in pool.imap_unordered( do_prefix, jobs ):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 735, in next
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/home/bdc34/docsim/docsim/loading/all_common_hashes.py", line 33, in do_prefix
    for hash, common, papers in by_prefix(db, start, end):
  File "/home/bdc34/docsim/docsim/loading/all_common_hashes.py", line 15, in by_prefix
    for row in db.table.read_rows(start_key=start, end_key=end):
  File "/home/bdc34/docsim/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/bigtable/row_data.py", line 485, in __iter__
    response = self._read_next_response()
  File "/home/bdc34/docsim/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/bigtable/row_data.py", line 474, in _read_next_response
    return self.retry(self._read_next, on_error=self._on_error)()
  File "/home/bdc34/docsim/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 288, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "/home/bdc34/docsim/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 190, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/home/bdc34/docsim/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/bigtable/row_data.py", line 470, in _read_next
    return six.next(self.response_iterator)
  File "/home/bdc34/docsim/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 109, in __next__
    raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.Aborted: 409 Error while reading table 'projects/testproject/instances/testinstance/tables/testtable' : 
Response was not consumed in time; terminating connection.(Possible causes: slow client data read or network problems)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this by calling read_rows with a much smaller range. The prefixes from table.sample_row_keys() were spanning around 1.5B rows. Bisecting each range 5 times to produce smaller ranges worked.

I bisected by padding out the start and end row_keys to the same length, converting those to ints and finding the midpoint.

Answer (score 0):

There could be different causes of this error. You might need to be sure that you are not facing a [hotspotting](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design-time-series#ensure_that_your_row_key_avoids_hotspotting) scenario here.

Also, you may check if you're reading many different rows in your table and that you are creating as few clients as possible. Performance can be hit too if you are reading a large range of row keys that contains only a small number of rows. You'll find more general advice on troubleshooting performance issues [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/performance#troubleshooting).

Comment: I'm not using time series data or row keys that should hotspot. I am creating a lot of clients because I want to process in parallel. My row space is very sparse. I am also reading ranges returned by sample prefix.